# How to name child nodes when importing from Excel to Firebase?

Tags: json, firebase, csv, firebase-realtime-database

I want to import data from Excel to Firebase. The import works fine, but I cannot figure out how to name the child nodes?

When I try this:

[image]

I get this in Firebase:

[image]

And when I add some numbers to the first cell for naming the child nodes like this:

[image]

The formatting gets all messed up like this:

The formatting gets all messed up like this:

```
 [
      {
        "Name": 123123,
        "Company": "Name1",
        "Email": "Company1",
        "Phonenumber": "Email1",
        "": 123,
        "__1": ""
      },
      {
        "Name": 123123,
        "Company": "Name2",
        "Email": "Company2",
        "Phonenumber": "Email2",
        "": 456,
        "__1": ""
      },
      {
        "Name": 123123,
        "Company": "Name3",
        "Email": "Company3",
        "Phonenumber": "Email3",
        "": 789,
        "__1": ""
      },
      {
        "Name": 2312312,
        "Company": "Name4",
        "Email": "Company4",
        "Phonenumber": "Email4",
        "": 101,
        "__1": ""
      },
      {
        "Name": 123123,
        "Company": "Name5",
        "Email": "Company5",
        "Phonenumber": "Email5",
        "": 123,
        "__1": ""
      }    
    ]
```

Ideally I would like to get autoID on each child node, but I can also go with my own ID input.

Comment: How are you importing this data into Firebase? That is probably where the order is determined.

Comment: I convert the Exel to `.csv` to ´json´and then import right in to the node I want the data to be

Comment: Can you show how you convert the CSV to JSON?

Comment: I use https://csvjson.com/csv2json

Comment: That JSON in your question looks like a fairly direct translation of the spreadsheet you're showing. A tool like csvjson.com/csv2json doesn't know about Firebase, so it is unlikely to generate Firebase push IDs. If you want such push IDs, you'll have to generate them yourself either in a conversion script - or by calling `push()` in the API repeatedly.

Comment: Your platform wasn't indicated but it would be fairly straightforward to craft a small app to read the text file and create the node keys (id's) firebase needs and then upload the objects. As mentioned, the import works very well, but the format of the data is very specific.